# Fix the code in stored procedure pl/sql(missing right parenthesis)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm new in pl/sql, that is why I'm looking for a help here.
I have a stored procedure which must generate a log table and trigger, but it shows an error:

Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "ASH.CREATE_LOG_TRIGGER", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 2
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Here is my code:

```
create or replace procedure create_log_trigger(p_table_name varchar2) IS
var2 varchar2(10000);
var1 varchar2(4000) := 'country VARCHAR2(100), iso_code VARCHAR2(20), vaccination_date DATE, total_vaccinations NUMBER(26, 5), 
people_vaccinated NUMBER(26, 5), people_fully_vaccinated NUMBER(26, 5), daily_vaccinations_raw NUMBER(26, 5), daily_vaccinations NUMBER(26, 5),
total_vaccinations_per_hundred NUMBER(26, 5), people_vaccinations_per_hundred NUMBER(26, 5), fully_vaccinations_per_hundred NUMBER(26, 5),
daily_vaccinations_per_million NUMBER(26, 5), vaccines VARCHAR2(128), source_name VARCHAR2(20), source_website VARCHAR2(20), 
 ACTION VARCHAR2(20), ACTIONAUTHOR VARCHAR2(20)';
var3 varchar2(4000) := 'country, iso_code, vaccination_date, total_vaccinations, 
people_vaccinated, people_fully_vaccinated, daily_vaccinations_raw, daily_vaccinations,
total_vaccinations_per_hundred, people_vaccinations_per_hundred, fully_vaccinations_per_hundred,
daily_vaccinations_per_million, vaccines, source_name, source_website, 
 ACTION, ACTIONAUTHOR';
var4 varchar2(4000) := 'new_country, new_iso_code, sysdate, new_ total_vaccinations, 
new_people_vaccinated, new_ people_fully_vaccinated, new_daily_vaccinations_raw, new_daily_vaccinations,
new_total_vaccinations_per_hundred, new_people_vaccinations_per_hundred, new_fully_vaccinations_per_hundred,
new_daily_vaccinations_per_million, new_ vaccines, new_source_name, new_source_website';
var5 varchar2(4000);
CURSOR cur_table is
    select column_name,data_type
    from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = p_table_name;
begin
    for i IN cur_table loop
        var1 := var1 ||', '||'old_'||i.column_name ||' '||i.data_type||', '||'new_'||i.column_name|| ' ' ||i.data_type;
        var3 := var3 ||', '||'old_'||i.column_name ||', '||'new_'||i.column_name;
        var5 := var5 ||', '||':old.'||i.column_name ||', '||':new.'||i.column_name;
    end loop;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table ' || p_table_name || '_LOG' || '(' || REPLACE(var1, 'VARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR(255)') || ')'; 
     var2 := 'create or replace trigger ' || p_table_name ||'_trig  
    AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE on '|| p_table_name ||' FOR EACH ROW
    declare
        new_country varchar2(20);
    BEGIN
        IF DELETING THEN
            select NVL(MAX(id), 0)+1 into new_country from ' || p_table_name || '_LOG;
            INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name || '_log('||var3||')
            VALUES('||var4||',''delete'',user'||var5||');
        END IF; 
        IF INSERTING THEN
            select NVL(MAX(id), 0)+1 into new_country from ' || p_table_name || '_LOG;
            INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name || '_log('||var3||')
            VALUES('||var4||',''insert'',user'||var5||');
        END IF;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            select NVL(MAX(id), 0)+1 into new_country from ' || p_table_name || '_LOG;
            INSERT INTO ' || p_table_name || '_log('||var3||')
            VALUES('||var4||',''update'',user'||var5||');
        END IF;
    END;';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var2;
end;
```

Comment: Code should be in the question as *text* not as an image.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Presumably the error is from the first `execute immediate` - is that line 28 in your version? - so output the command before you execute it. The `replace()` looks like it should be in the loop; aren't you going to end up with things like `country_id varchar2(255)(100)`? But why not use the actual size from `user_tab_columns`?

Comment: Okay, I'll try!

Comment: I recommend that you refactor the code so that you are calling EXECUTE IMMEDIATE on a variable, rather than a mixture of vars and literal text above. If you do that, you can debug and evaluate the var and see SQL that is being called (or output it as Alex mentions above). Its highly likely that there's a simple syntax issue in your SQL (maybe even a missing parenthesis). As it stands now, it will be very difficult to debug this without a refactor. I might also call EXECUTE IMMEDIATE once for the create table SQL and a second time for the create trigger SQL but that's just me.

Comment: Why are you bothering with a procedure? It seems you already know the exact columns and their definitions (var1, var2, ...) . Further it seems valid for creating 1 table and 1 trigger, and then executed 1 time.